# MATLAB rescaling a loglog plot

Tags: matlab, plot

[image]

How can I rescale the vertical axis of a loglog plot so all my lines of my graph starts at `10^0`?

```
loglog(ddt,Sqone,'b',ddt,Sqtwo,'m',ddt,Sqthree,'r',ddt,Sqfour,'y',ddt,Sqfive,'c');
title('Partition Function for CRSP Index on Log-Log Plot')
```

In my code above you see that `ddt=1:500` and `Sqone`, `Sqtwo`, `Sqthree`, etc... are all my various values for different functions (which changes according to the exponent 1,2,3,4,5).

Comment: What about scaling 'Sqone', 'Sqtwo', 'Sqthree', ... .

Comment: Ok I guess that i have to use the command YScale - ill see if I can figure it out

Comment: @CharlesMartineau: I think I'm still not sure what the goal is here, do you want to shift the curves to start at 10^0 in the y-values, or do you want to set the axis limits (show a certain range of values)?

Comment: @Amro Yes I want to shift the curves to start at 10^0 in the y-values

Comment: @CharlesMartineau: in that case do: `y = y-y(1)+10^0;` for each of the variables: `Sqone`, `Sqtwo`, ...

Comment: @Amro thanks! Yes I can simply do a vertical displacement in my data! thank you!

Comment: @CharlesMartineau: glad I could help, I posted an answer as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can shift the data itself to move the plots in the y-direction:

```
%# transform each of the variables: Sqone, Sqtwo, ..
y = y - y(1)  + 10^0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`set(gca,'YLim',max(get(gca,'YLim'),1))`